# Cheese delayed in the mail

Tags: food-safety, cheese

My nephew sent Truffle Gouda & Herve Mons Gabietou along with some Genoa Salami and bread via USPS overnight mail on Weds, 12/23.  However, it did not arrive until today, 12/26. Would the cheese still be okay to eat?

Comment: Was it declared as perishable goods? If not, it's hard to say what temperatures it was exposed to. Also, if sent by (I presume) Express Mail, there should be some guarantee if the stated delivery date was not met.

Comment: Thank you!  Not sure that it was declared.  My nephew is getting his money back because of the guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

If the cheese is packaged in a vacuum wrapper, it should be OK, certainly the gouda. This method of packaging allows gouda style cheeses to be transported without cooling even in summer.
I am not familiar with the other cheese but would myself be willing to eat or serve it.

Cheese was made, in summer when the cows gave plenty of milk, to preserve that milk to later in the year. A few days in winter transport should not hurt it.

US food safety standards may not be met during transport but in winter hot temperatures are very unlikely.

Answer (score -2):

As long as the rind is still encasing the cheese, it should be just fine, as Gouda is aged for weeks anyway, and its salt content preserves it.

Comment: Gouda is aged for months up to two years, in the Netherlands at least.